How to reduce white space above each chapter start?
I'm mixing geometry, fancyhdr and fancychap packages so all I've tried didn't work. I would like to reduce the white space above the title of the table of contents, but leave it just as it is for the rest of the chapters.
Top margin of the geometry package shouldn't be modified in order to not break the document layout.
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}

% -- MARGIN AND LAYOUT --
    \usepackage{geometry} 
    \geometry{
     includefoot,
     a4paper,
     total={170mm,257mm},
     left=27mm,
     top=40mm,
     headsep=10mm,
     right=27mm,
     bottom=27mm,
     footskip=15mm
    }
    
    % Interlineado
    \linespread{1.4}
% -- MARGIN AND LAYOUT --

\usepackage{blindtext}

% -- FANCY HEADER, FOOTER AND CHAPTERS --
    \usepackage{fancyhdr} % Headers and footers
    \usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}

    % Header and footer
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \cfoot{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.3mm}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0mm} % 0.3mm
    \renewcommand{\footruleskip}{0mm} % 5mm
    
    \fancypagestyle{plain}{% % <-- this is new
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}

    % Redefine chaptermark to preserve case 
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{Capítulo \thechapter\ : #1}{}}
    \renewcommand{\chaptername}{Capítulo}

% -- FANCY HEADER, FOOTER AND CHAPTERS --

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand*\contentsname{ÍNDICE DE CONTENIDOS}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{INTRODUCCIÓN}
% Change the margin square color for the next chapter
% NOTE: Replaced the broken definition by a working usage of \marginsquare
%\renewcommand{\applymarginsquare}{\AddEverypageHook{\marginsquare{marginColor1}}}
\section{Some dummy text}
\blindtext[10]

\end{document}


I do not recommend such inconsistency. But if you really want it:
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}

% -- MARGIN AND LAYOUT --
    \usepackage{geometry} 
    \geometry{
     includefoot,
     a4paper,
     total={170mm,257mm},
     left=27mm,
     top=40mm,
     headsep=10mm,
     right=27mm,
     bottom=27mm,
     footskip=15mm
    }
    
    % Interlineado
    \linespread{1.4}
% -- MARGIN AND LAYOUT --

\usepackage{blindtext}

% -- FANCY HEADER, FOOTER AND CHAPTERS --
    \usepackage{fancyhdr} % Headers and footers
    \usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}

    % Header and footer
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \cfoot{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.3mm}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0mm} % 0.3mm
    \renewcommand{\footruleskip}{0mm} % 5mm
    
    \fancypagestyle{plain}{% % <-- this is new
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}

    % Redefine chaptermark to preserve case 
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{Capítulo \thechapter\ : #1}{}}
    \renewcommand{\chaptername}{Capítulo}

% -- FANCY HEADER, FOOTER AND CHAPTERS --

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand*\contentsname{ÍNDICE DE CONTENIDOS}
\AddToHookNext{cmd/@makeschapterhead/before}{\vspace*{-50pt}}% Move the next
                                % not numbered chapter 50pt upwards
\tableofcontents

\chapter{INTRODUCCIÓN}
\section{Some dummy text}
\blindtext[10]

\end{document}



The chapter style hardwires a 50pt space above the chapter title.
Here's a patch (27pt has been gaged by eye).
Look at the other changes I made, most with <---. Using setspace is better than just using \linespread.
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\setlocalecaption{spanish}{contents}{ÍNDICE DE CONTENIDOS}

% -- MARGIN AND LAYOUT --
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{
  includefoot,
  a4paper,
%  total={170mm,257mm},% <--- overspecification
  left=27mm,
  top=40mm,
  headsep=10mm,
  right=27mm,
  bottom=27mm,
  footskip=15mm,
  headheight=15.72pt, % <--- fancyhdr tells you this
}

% Interlineado
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.4}
% -- MARGIN AND LAYOUT --

\usepackage{blindtext}

% -- FANCY HEADER, FOOTER AND CHAPTERS --
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Headers and footers
\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}

% Header and footer
\pagestyle{fancy}
\cfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.3mm}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0mm} % 0.3mm
\renewcommand{\footruleskip}{0mm} % 5mm

\fancypagestyle{plain}{% % <-- this is new
\fancyhf{}\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}

% Redefine chaptermark to preserve case 
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{Capítulo \thechapter\ : #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Capítulo}

% -- FANCY HEADER, FOOTER AND CHAPTERS --

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{verbatim}

%%% fix the spacing of chapters
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{50\p@}{0pt}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{50\p@}{27pt}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{INTRODUCCIÓN}

\section{Some dummy text}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}


